# Internet Explorer 8,9 reload loop with client router (Page.js + history.js)

Tags: internet-explorer, history.js, html5-history, page.js

I am woriking on a project and using page.js client router which uses History API (Project works perfectly fine in all browsers, IE 10+). But it doesn`t work on IE 8, 9. When I am trying to open my web application base path in IE lt9 I get infinite redirect loop. I am using HTML5-History-API polyfill (watch link in P.S.).

This is my router.js file. I got page.js and history.js included in the head of index.html

```
//callbacks modules
var index = require("./router callbacks/index");
var contacts = require("./router callbacks/contacts");
var notFound = require("./router callbacks/notFound");

//history redirect for IE lt9
history.redirect("/", "/content-library/app/");

page.base('/content-library/app');
page('/', index);
page('/contacts',contacts);
page('*', notFound);
page();
```

[Redirect loop when I am trying to launch first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5EGE.png)

[Returns html markup but doesn`t initiate callback function to render full page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFZjk.png)

I know that history API isn`t supported IE10-, but as far as I followed all the instructions in page.js they are saying it should work fine with HTML5-History-API polyfill. So now I am thinking whether there is any solution or I just should changed my router to hash.

As far as I researched in web it may be something concerning history.redirect, but as I am looking into the library it should work fine.

P.S.
Can`t add more than 2 links due to low reputation:
page.js - visionmedia.github.io/page.js/
HTML5-History-API - github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API

Thank you!